# How to stop repeating of rows in inner<c:forEach>tag of JSTL in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

My rows under the inner foreach tag are repeating itself for all the values of outer forEach tag.
My code is

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${ref.refarray_vac1(param.datepicker)}">
<c:forEach var="r" items="${ref.refernece(param.ref_logtime)}"> 


<tr bgcolor="darkgray ">
<td><c:out value="${r.logtime}"></c:out></td>

<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(r.beam_current) ne 0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${r.beam_current}" maxFractionDigits="2"    minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${r.beam_current}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>


<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(r.beam_energy) ne 0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${r.beam_energy}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${r.beam_energy}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>


<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(r.st2_vs2_bag1_rb) > 0.0}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${r.st2_vs2_bag1_rb}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##E0" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:out value="OFF"></c:out> </c:otherwise></c:choose></td>

<tr bgcolor="cornsilk">

<td><c:out value="${row.logtime}"></c:out></td>

<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(row.beam_current) > 0.0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${row.beam_current}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
 ${(mm)}
 </c:when>
 <c:otherwise>
 ${row.beam_current}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>


<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(row.beam_energy) > 0.0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${row.beam_energy}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${row.beam_energy}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>


<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(row.st2_vs2_bag1_rb) > 0.0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${row.st2_vs2_bag1_rb}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##E0" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
 ${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:out value="OFF"></c:out></c:otherwise></c:choose></td>

</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

I want that for only one value of outer forEach loop only one value of inner forEach loop should be displayed.No repetition of inner forEach loop rows should be there.

**EDIT-1**
My output displayed is of the form-
[image]

**The values shown in light color(beam_current 10.01) are repeating itself for each value in gray color**.Suppose the outer ForEach tag has 22 rows then each value of inner loop will repeat 22 times.

**I want that 10.01 should be shown only one time when beam_current is 10 in gray color ,then another value of inner forEach loop should be displayed corresponding to beam_current 20.02 in gray color and so on.**

Comment: tiddi, I still think my answer can help you. It does not sound like you want two `forEach` loops: you want only one. It sounds like your code is doing exactly what you're telling it to: the outer loop does not proceed to the next value until the inner loop has reached the last value, and then the inner loop resets to the first value! Here is a Java example that you can run: https://ideone.com/gJtTt2

Answer (score 1):

For inner loop, use the `end="0"` attribute of `c:forEach`

It will iterate the loop, for only first item of the inner forEach.

```
<c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />
<c:forEach var="row" items="${ref.refarray_vac1(param.datepicker)}">
    <c:forEach var="r" items="${ref.refernece(param.ref_logtime)}" begin="${count}" end="${count}"> 
        ...
        ...

        <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page" />
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: ,When I do so then the outer forEach loop is repeating its value.Please see my Edit.

Comment: Does outer loop and inner loop having same size?

Comment: Oh, I thought they would have the same size. What's supposed to happen if their size differs, @tiddirastogi?

Comment: 0 should be displayed,but till now I'm assuming they have same size.i can't implement our concept as then I have to calculate the difference of there values .Is there some any other way.Moreover I'm getting an exception**javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '1' not found on type java.lang.String**????on line **<td><c:out value="${r.logtime[i.count]}"></c:out></td>**

Comment: Then end="0" will not work. I think you need set a counter for the inner loop and then begin the inner loop from that count and end on the same counter, dynamically. It will not repeat the previous looped value.

Comment: @SandeepPatange .It worked.Can I do something like that when my beam_current value is near to 10 from list2 then the value which is near to 10 in list1 shoul be repeated as many times I have value near to 10 in list2.

Comment: I think you can try removing the count variable from page scope, when beam_current value reaches near to 10. you can remove count variable using, <c:remove var="count" scope="page"/>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to iterate through each collection using the same index, like in this pseudocode:

```
listA = [x, y, z]
listB = [a, b, c]
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++):
  print listA[i]
  print listB[i]
```

To do this, you need to remove one of the `forEach` loops, and use the index of the remaining loop to access the other collection. For example:

```
<c:forEach var="listAValue" items="${listA}" varStatus="i">
  <c:out value="${listA[i.count]}" />
  <c:out value="${listB[i.count]}" />
```

I hope this helps, but if it doesn't I recommend you clarify your question.

Comment: @DavidS.I got exception **Property '1' not found on type comparision_list.Comaprision**